I cant get my gsap animation to work on the way backup
I've been working on a website and have been trying to get my animation to work. Oddly enough it works when you click on it and it expands but it doesnt work when you click on it again which should shrink it. It does work when you shrink it if another foodCard is expanded and you're shrinking a different foodCard. Does anyone know why this might be happening?


import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Star from '../Star/Star';
import MacroTable from "../Macros/MacroTable";
import { FaLeaf, FaBreadSlice, FaHandRock } from 'react-icons/fa';
import gsap from "gsap";
import {useGSAP} from "@gsap/react";

function FoodCard({ foodItem, updateRating }) {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const cardRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let tl = gsap.timeline();
    if (isExpanded) {
      gsap.to(cardRef.current, {
        height: 'auto',
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: 'linear'
      });
    } else {
      gsap.to(cardRef.current, {
        height: '8rem',
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: 'linear'
      });
    }
  }, [isExpanded]);

  const averageRating = (foodItem.rating / (foodItem.rating_count || 1)).toFixed(1);

  const handleRating = (newRating) => {
    updateRating(foodItem.title, newRating);
  };

  let labelsArray = [];
  try {
    if (Array.isArray(foodItem.labels)) {
      labelsArray = foodItem.labels;
    } else if (typeof foodItem.labels === "string" && foodItem.labels.trim()) {
      labelsArray = JSON.parse(foodItem.labels);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error parsing labels for ${foodItem.title}:`, error);
    labelsArray = [];
  }

  const isVegetarian = labelsArray.includes("vegetarian");
  const hasGluten = labelsArray.includes("gluten");
  const highProtein = labelsArray.includes("protein");

  return (
    <div
      ref={cardRef}
      className={`relative bg-gray-700 text-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-6 cursor-pointer
       hover:bg-gray-600 transition-all duration-300 ${
        isExpanded ? "w-auto h-auto" : "w-64 h-64"
      }`}
      onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
    >
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">{foodItem.title}</h2>
        <div className="absolute top-2 right-2 flex justify-end items-start space-x-2">
          {isVegetarian && <FaLeaf title="Vegetarian" className="text-green-400" />}
          {hasGluten && <FaBreadSlice title="Contains Gluten" className="text-yellow-500" />}
          {highProtein && <FaHandRock title="High Protein" className="text-red-400" />}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex items-center mt-2">
        <Star currentRating={averageRating} onRate={handleRating} />
        <span className="ml-2 text-sm">({foodItem.rating_count} reviews)</span>
      </div>

      {isExpanded && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <p className="text-gray-300">{foodItem.description}</p>
          <MacroTable macros={foodItem.nutritional_info} />
          <div className="mt-2">
            <h3 className="font-semibold">Portion Size:</h3>
            <p className="text-gray-300">{foodItem.portion_size}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FoodCard;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




Transitions in CSS don’t make height: auto work.
CSS Grid comes to the rescue!
https://dev.to/francescovetere/css-trick-transition-from-height-0-to-auto-21de
